With terraform azure, how to allow update setting 'Client application requirement'?
Hope you can help me with a crazy situation. See below screenshot and i would like to have setting 'Client application requirement' with value 'allow requests only from this application itself' and not 'Allow requests from any application (Not recommended)'

Below my terraform file:
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "terra_webapp" {
 resource_group_name = var.web_app_resource_group_name
 name                = var.web_app_name
 location            = var.web_app_location
 service_plan_id     = var.service_plan_id
 tags                = var.tags

 https_only = true
 app_settings = {
   WEBSITE_AUTH_AAD_ALLOWED_TENANTS = "<TenantID>"
 }

 site_config {
   minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
 }

 auth_settings_v2 {
   auth_enabled           = true
   require_authentication = true
   require_https          = true
   runtime_version        = "~1"
   default_provider       = "azureactivedirectory"
   unauthenticated_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"

login {
  token_store_enabled            = true
  token_refresh_extension_time   = 6
  allowed_external_redirect_urls = []
}

   active_directory_v2 {
     client_id            = "<appClientID>"
     tenant_auth_endpoint = "https://sts.windows.net/<TenantID>/v2.0"

   }
 }

}
Official documentation from terraform here and i try all settings without luck (especially the one with allowed_xxx)
I struggle to find a solution. Any idea or suggestions ?
regards

you created the resource via terraform apply, then if you manually change it on azure and next run a terraform Plan, it should show the difference

After exploring on your requirement, I found that it is not possible to set up additional checks of identity provider as of now. It can be done with CLI or portal. @Paul

@HelderSepulveda: yes i apply your suggestion but unfortunately it does not give me settings which has been modified.

@Jahnavi: thanks for your help. This is what i understand also. It's pity that we cannot change it for now. Do you have any idea and when we could this with terraform ?

if it can be done via the CLI it can be done in the terraform provider, report it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=Feature_Request.yml&title=Support+for+azurerm_windows_web_app
